# Change event not firing when setting option on select item on JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

I am manually setting a value to a JQuery mobile select menu like this (I need to do this when my page loads):

```
$('#ddlCountries').val(1);
```

Then updating the UI:

```
$('#ddlCountries').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

But the change event doesn't get fired at all. I do an ajax request when that event fires.

If I run:

```
$('#ddlCountries').change();
```

Then the ajax request is executed.

Is there a way to actually simulate a manual change/select operation inside the select menu?

Comment: `$('#ddlCountries').selectmenu("refresh", true).change();`?

Comment: Yeah, thanks $('#ddlCountries').val(1).selectmenu("refresh", true).change(); did the trick. Though I was looking for something that didn't require to explicitly call an event.